# Python Decimal modf

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the most efficient way to get the integer part and fractional part of a python (python 3) `Decimal`?

This is what I have right now:

```
from decimal import *
>>> divmod(Decimal('1.0000000000000003')*7,Decimal(1))
(Decimal('7'), Decimal('2.1E-15'))
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `math.modf` ([Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.modf))

```
>>> math.modf(1.0000000000000003)
(2.220446049250313e-16, 1.0)
python2.7 -m timeit -s 'import math' 'math.modf(1.0000000000000003)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.191 usec per loop
```

The `divmod` method:

```
python2.7 -m timeit -s 'import decimal' 'divmod(decimal.Decimal(1.0000000000000003),decimal.Decimal(1))'
1000 loops, best of 3: 39.8 usec per loop
```

I believe the more efficient is `math.modf`

## Edit

I guess even more simpler and efficient way is to just convert the string to an integer:

```
>>>a = int(Decimal('1.0000000000000003'))
1

>>>python2.7 -m timeit -s 'import decimal' 'int(decimal.Decimal('1.0000000000000003'))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 11.2 usec per loop
```

To get the decimal part:

```
>>>int(Decimal('1.0000000000000003')) - a
3E-16
```

Comment: Of course it is. Anything that operates on `float` will be faster than anything that operates on `decimal.Decimal`. However, the question is about `decimal.Decimal`, not `float`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Does it really matter to the user which one he uses? If float is faster, then why not just convert string to float. Unless the conversion is more costly.

Comment: Accuracy is a problem, that is why I'm using `Decimal` and not `float`

Answer (score 2):

- integer part

```py
123.456 // 1
# 123.0
```

- fractional part

```py
123.456 % 1
# 0.45600000000000307
```

- fractional part with precision

```py
p = 3 # precision as 3
123.456 % 1 * (10**p // 1 / 10**p)
# 0.456
```

- automatically detect precision

```py
def modf(f):
    sf = str(f)
    i = sf.find(".")
    p  = len(sf)-i-1
    inter = f // 1
    fractional = f % 1 * 10**p // 1 / 10**p
    return inter,fractional
modf(123.456)
# (123, 0.456)
```

> `modf()` is **20** **microseconds**(1/1000000 seconds) **slower** than `math.modf()`